# How do you use the @input variable in Angular parent-child communication

Tags: angular

In the communication between parent and child components of angular, how to use variables decorated with @ input in child components? For example, the following code:

```
@input str : string;
```

Then I can use it in the ngoninit() function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log ("str is:",  this.str );
}
```

It works normally, and I can see the content in the console.
But if I want to use this variable in another place in this class, for example, in the following functions:

```
private _ str : string;
strVal(){
this._ str= this.str ;
console.log ( str is:", this._ str);
}
```

It can be compiled, but there is an error in the console, and the prompt is "undefined".

How to solve similar problems? thank you.

Comment: why are assigning the same value to another variable?also when is the function strVal() called?

Comment: I just added ngOnchnages to get the new value of your @Input Value

Answer (score 1):

You must use `()` for `Input`.
Example:

```
@Input() data: string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write `@Input() str: string;`

Also make sure, that the function `strVal();` is called.

An easy way to test this is to call the function in the `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.strVal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to avoid the `undefined` issue you can start by givint to your `input` a default value.

```
@Input()
str = 'default'; // Or you can just let it empty ''
```

Why you are having the `undefined`. In your code I see

```
console.log ( str is:", this._ str); // There is a " missing here
console.log ( "str is:", this._ str); // I think the undefined you are having,
// is not about the str input but about the "str" in this line where " was missing (str is:")
```